# Copy/Paste in Edit Form on sharepoint list

Tags: list, list-form

I am not able to copy from the existing comments or description fields in an Edit form in my sharepoint list. Copy/Paste does work on the View form, but I'd like it to work on the Edit form as well. Does anyone have any experience with this and know of a way to make it work?

Comment: Hi Kyle. Both copy and paste don't work? Or just paste? Do you have the same problem in any other browser?

Comment: Did you try to use copy/paste in the ribbon? Is it working?